# How to get the listview layout excluding header?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I need to apply a drawable background to the entire list, excluding the header view (to which I need to apply this background separately). Currently using my adapter, I can apply this background to individual `ListView` items, and I can apply the background to the entire `ListView` (including any headers or footers). How can I get a Layout containing only the List part of the `ListView`?

```
monthListView.addHeaderView(singleMonthLayout,null,false);
monthListView.setAdapter(viewAdapter);
```

I think that `ListView` simply considers header as a list item with -1 index or something, so I'm not sure if there is a proper way to do this. I want to apply a rounded-corner background to the List excluding the header. I cannot add header as a separate view as I need it to scroll along with the `ListView`.

Comment: instead of using header-view create separate view for header and below it add your list-view and add custom background to list-view only

Comment: I need the header to scroll along with the `ListView`, so I cant add it as a separate view

Comment: I think, even if you created separate view and added it as headerview , it would be scrolled along with listview. Didn't you try?

Comment: The header is a separate view. You add the separate view using `addHeaderView()`.  @YoLo here is asking whether I can add the view as a separate view above the `ListView`, having no relation to the `ListView` itself. I cannot do this as I need that view to scroll along with my list.